# While loop != is not working as expected?

Tags: python

**The Situation**

I was going to create a text-based  adventure game for fun then I ran into this problem where it seems to be in an infinite loop

**The Code**

```py
def adventure():
    print("You are in front of the gate of the tower. Will you Enter?")
    ch = ""
    while ch.lower() != "y" or ch.lower() != "n":
        print("Please Choose")
        ch = input("[Y] or [N]: ")
        print(ch)
    print("You are out of the while loop")

adventure()
```

**The Goal**

I wanted to make it so that the user must choose Y or N as input but even though ch = y or n the program
still won't get out of the while loop.

**Example Output**

> You are in front of the towers' gate. Will you Enter?
>
> Please Choose
>
> [Y] or [N]:
>
> y
>
> Please Choose
>
> [Y] or [N]: n
>
> n
>
> Please Choose [Y] or [N]:
>
> a
>
> Please Choose [Y] or [N]:

**The Question**

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Classic mistake - use `and`, not `or` in your loop condition

Comment: A string can't be equal to `"y"` and `"n"` at the same time, so your `while` condition is always `True`.

Comment: Have you considered stripping the input string, via `ch = input("[Y] or [N]:").strip()`, in case it contains any whitespace?

Comment: Safe to say you're not having fun debugging this, eh?

Comment: You might want to review [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: hint : `"n" != "y"`

Comment: To put it another way: all strings are different from at least one of `"y"` and `"n"`. You need to be careful when translating natural language into logic; "x is neither a nor b" is "x is not a, *and* x is not b" – not "x is not a, *or* x is not b".

Comment: you could also have it like `while ch.lower() not in ("y", "n"):` if you don't want to use `and` and `or`

Comment: Do this: while ch.lower() NOT IN ['y', 'n'].........

Comment: Do this: while ch.lower() NOT IN ['y', 'n'].........

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Thank you very much. That fixed my problem.

Comment: @rv.kvetch yep, I had this problem for like 30 mins before I was able to ask this question since I also just asked another question and had to wait to be able to post again XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probem here is you are using the `or` operator not the `and` operator

It should be:

```py
    print("You are in front of the gate of the tower. Will you Enter?")
    ch = ""
    while ch.lower() != "y" and ch.lower() != "n":
        print("Please Choose")
        ch = input("[Y] or [N]: ")
        print(ch)
    print("You are out of the while loop")
```

Answer (score 0):

When designing your `while` loop, it's sometimes easier to think about the condition that makes you exit the loop, and then just negate it.

In your case, you exit the loop when the user enters `"y"` or `"n"`:

```
while not (ch.lower() == "y" or ch.lower() == "n"):
    ...
```

Later, you can simplify the condition using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

***First Step***

```
while not ch.lower() == "y" and not ch.lower() == "n":
    ...
```

***Second Step***

```
while ch.lower() != "y" and ch.lower() != "n":
    ...
```

Sometimes python developers prefers the usage of `not ==` instead of `!=`, it depends on you code conventions.